# Chrome doesn't show the favicon

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I can't manage to show the favicon of this site http://www.lowcoupling.com on chrome. 
I have checked it with Safari and the favicon is correctly shown
How should i fix it?

**UPDATE**

here follows the first part of my css

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html b:render='false' b:version='2' class='v2' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
  <head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">


    <b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>
    <title>Low Coupling</title>
    <meta content='!' name='fragment'/>
    <meta content='dynamic' name='blogger-template'/>
    <meta content='IE=9,chrome=1' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>
    <meta content='initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=4.0, user-scalable=yes, width=device-width' name='viewport'/>

   <meta name='text:Disqus Shortname' content='' />

<!-- Le styles -->
   <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type='text/css'>
    .hero-unit {
        background-color: white;
        min-height: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  min-width: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;

    }

      body {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
      }


      .sidebar-nav {
        padding: 9px 0;
      }

      .tweet{
          margin-top: 10px;

      }
      p.centredimg {
       text-align: center;
      }

      }
    </style>
   <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shCoreDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shCore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJava.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">SyntaxHighlighter.all();</script>



<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-41136618-1', 'lowcoupling.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src='../assets/js/html5shiv.js'></script>
    <![endif]-->
<link rel="shortcut icon"  href='http://sites.google.com/site/lowcoupling/favicon_16x16.ico'/>
  </head>
  <body>

<div class='navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top'>
```

Comment: Have you cleared your cache in chrome? That is usually the culprit. I can see it well on Safari.

Comment: I just checked the website on Chrome and indeed, it is not showing up. Is this an issue because the website is on tumblr? I don't usually work with tumblr so I don't know how to go about checking this.

Comment: the website is on tumblr but the you can configure the css as you like so I guess I am doing something wrong in the css

Comment: Try saving your icon as favicon.ico in the root directory. That's more cross-browser compatible than using a link or a meta tag.

Comment: unfortunately I guess I can't do that as it is a tumblr blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]You have your `meta` tags and `stylesheet` includes within the `body` of your document and not the `head`

[image] This is your code. The head section is closed, for clarity. The body section is open thus showing you that the tags i was referring to reside here.

Comment: are you sure? it actually doesn't seem to me

Comment: it is strange because if I look at the css and at the source retrieve from the browser it doesn't look like the pic you posted. the head contains the meta tags and the body tag doens't have the data-twttr-rendered attribute

Comment: i'm using chrome dev tools on a mac. The fact that you are having `meta` tag issues, in this case with a favicon, would definietaly indicate that this is the cause. Maybe heck your code for a duplicate `body` of `head` tag.

Comment: I posted the first part of my css

Comment: @lowcoupling I see the same thing as Vector does: meta, title tags in the body and not in the header. I also see a bunch of 404 errors and some javascript errors, which I doubt are the problem but thought I'd mention :)

Comment: thank you for your kind effort I obviously do believe you but I can't see what my cause it could you please check the css I posted? thank you again

Comment: From your posted code i would assume this is a wordpress template. If this is the case the problem could be with encoding/including defined within a function somewhere. This has happened to many users (meta tags appearing in body) that have used wordpress templates.

Comment: @lowcoupling The tags the header tags that are appearing in the body all seem to be children of a tag that looks like this: `<b:include data="blog" name="all-head-content" ...>` -- wondering what that is and if it's the culprit.

Comment: I am checking it with Chrome dev tools and I am seeing the same thing. However it is different than what depicted when I ask Chrome to visualize the page source.

Comment: That include you are reffering to should be included within `<head>` tags

Comment: Fine! it works now. It was about the tag @Sunil mentioned which was probably an old wordpress tag (as suggested by @Vector) remained after a migration of the website.

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you add `type="image/png"` like so:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://sites.google.com/site/lowcoupling/lowcouplingFavicon-01.png">
```

See [this reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#How_to_use). Maybe even remove the 'shortcut' bit, and just have `rel="icon"` and if nothing else works, switch from a png to an ico file.

Comment: I have tried all the things you suggested now I am using an ico file but still can't see the favicon