# Favicon.ico can't show up in the Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, favicon

Something werid happens to me, I am going to build my personal website, put `favicon.ico` in the `header.html`, like below:

> `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">`

And clean up the history records of the browser, `Firefox` shows the icon, but `Chrome` doesn't show up.

I can't figure out the reason, please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome doesn't show the favicon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869112/chrome-doesnt-show-the-favicon)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you have non-header markups in your `head`. For example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <div>This div has nothing to do here. It's a "body" markup.</div>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
     ...
  </body>
</html>
```

When Chrome finds a non-header markups in the `head` (eg. `div`, `span`, `p`...), it considers the header to be completed (even if it is not technically closed) and everything that follows is supposed to be in the body. And since the favicon markup doesn't work when it is in the body...

This behavior is specific to Chrome, this is why your favicon work in Firefox.